# Weird Error "Call to a member function move() on a non-object" In Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm adding a file upload function to my form in Symfony2. I've followed the [documentation here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html), but I keep getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function move() on a non-object

The thing is, the line of code it refers to is this:

```
$this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->file->getClientOriginalName());
```

This is a line of code that I took from the documentation. I'm not entirely sure why it's moaning about the `move()` though. I have checked to see if I'm missing any files but I'm not.

Do I have to create a reference to this? Or am I missing a file?

Cheers

**EDIT:**

I have added the following code to the beginning of the `upload()` function:

```
// the file property can be empty if the field is not required
if (null === $this->file) {
    return;
}
```

However, I have now been given the following errors:

> 1/2: Exception: Serialization of
>   'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed

and

> 2/2: Exception:
>   Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\DataCollector\DoctrineDataCollector::serialize()
>   must return a string or NULL

I don't know if what I've done has fixed the previous error as I have now been presented with these errors.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot persit the file property, you need 2 properties in your entity, one to hold the UploadedFile and another one to hold the filename (which is persisted).

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
public $path;    

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
public $file;
```

You add only the `$file` property to your form.

Comment: Hi @LouTerrailloune, I have the same problem that question here but I can not fix it. I know it has to do with my property photo is of type string, but do not know how to put such images to be saved in a directory and save only the file name in the database. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855510/error-call-to-a-member-function-move-on-a-non-object-in-symfony2) you can see my problem if you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add function

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload() {
    if (null !== $this->file) {
            $this->path = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
    }
}
```

then in upload function

```
public function upload() {
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path)) {
        // ok uploaded
    }else{
       echo "failed to upload";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have

```
$this->file == null
```

Check that you have instanced it

Comment: I have this line in my Entity file in an upload() function. Still no joy :(